# Process Builder Error:The formula expression is invalid-Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time)

Tags: error, process, builder

I am creating a Process builder on case object. There are 3 criteria checks on a case record:
 1. Case Record Type = Technical Support
 2. Status = Re-Opened
 3. Closure Reason = No response from the customer.

[image]
When this criteria meets then the **'Immediate action'** should be:
Case.Follow_up_date__c [Date/Time field] = Now().
[image]

I am trying to do the same but getting the error "The formula expression is invalid-Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time)."

This is difficult to understand why the type is being said incompatible. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything before `NOW()` in the formula expression.

Otherwise it is actually returning boolean value upon comparing with `Follow_up_date__c` and `Now()`

Desired formula will be:

- Field: Follow-up Date
- Type: Formula
- Value: NOW()

Comment: Thanks Santanu. The syntax error not coming. But the rule does not seem to work,, it is not updating the field to now().  Any suggestions?

Comment: Then your criteria may not be matching

Comment: Yeah I checked that already. Thank you for your quick response. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It should be simply Like this  **Follow_up_Date __c    Formula    NOW()**